# jenkins not able to find virtualenv

Tags: jenkins, virtualenvwrapper

I want to activate my virtualenv via jenkins. But I am facing problems in that.

Here are the commands,

```
cd /home/luvpreet/Desktop/vogo/influxdata
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon influxdata
./manage.py test
```

And I am getting this error,

```
+ echo 'ERROR: Environment '\''influxdata'\'' does not exist. Create it with '\''mkvirtualenv influxdata'\''.'
ERROR: Environment 'influxdata' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv influxdata'.
+ return 1
```

The shell executable is `/bin/bash`

It is saying that influxdata virtualenv does not exist, but it does.

Why it is showing this ? How can I run my virtualenv ?

Comment: If your job is building on a slave, then please make sure that the virtualenv exists on the slave filesystem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer,

As jenkins user home folder is `/var/lib/jenkins`,

so, it was looking at `/var/lib/jenkins/.virtualenvs` instead of other users home directory.

So, firstly I changed directory to the hme folder of other user and then activated my existing virtualenv.

```
cd /home/luvpreet/
cd .virtualenvs/influxdata/bin
source activate
```